# Is there a default CAfile/CApath location for solaris openssl and curl?

Tags: openssl, curl, solaris

I have already tried several locations and neither openssl nor curl recognize the certificate file I have placed there.

I have tried these paths:

```
/etc/certs
/etc/sfw/openssl/certs
/etc/ssl/certs
/usr/local/ssl/certs
/usr/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

And does the file have to be a certain name?

I know it is possible to just specify the path in the command or use an environment var but is there an actual default file path?

My system is solaris 10.

I have compiled recent versions of openssl and curl: `curl 7.45.0 (sparc-sun-solaris2.10) OpenSSL/1.0.2e`

Comment: You might use [truss](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Unix/Solaris/SOLARIS_UsingthetrussCommandinSolaris.shtml) to trace your curl call and see where it looks for the certificates.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [site](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) there is a build time option for libcurl that specifies where the path to the CA bundle is:

> Add the CA cert for your server to the existing default CA cert
>   bundle. The default path of the CA bundle used can be changed by
>   running configure with the --with-ca-bundle option pointing out the
>   path of your choice.

In addition to the compile time option there is an environment variable that can be used to point to the CA bundle:

> If you're using the curl command line tool, you can specify your own
>   CA cert path by setting the environment variable CURL_CA_BUNDLE to the
>   path of your choice.

It does mention a default path of:

> If you're using the curl command line tool on Windows, curl will
>   search for a CA cert file named "curl-ca-bundle.crt" in these
>   directories and in this order:
>
> ```
> application's directory
> current working directory
> Windows System directory (e.g. C:\windows\system32)
> Windows Directory (e.g. C:\windows)
> all directories along %PATH%
> ```

Comment: I saw that documentation. And, I find the lack of mention of what the default path is a bit odd. I believe the location/paths varies per OS type but still the documentation could be better.

Comment: You could build libcurl to have any path you like I suppose.

Comment: Its supposed to be possible and I investigated that and couldn't figure it out. I don't see any configure options. Do you know how?

Comment: download the source, change into the directory, and run ./configure --with-ca-bundle /path/you/want/to/be/default.file.ca